# How to specify in DOT file that edges go upwards

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I want to render a directed graph like:

```
    A
   ^ ^
  /   \
 /     \
B       C
```

But no matter what order I put the statements in, dot insists on generating an image that looks like:

```
B       C
 \     /
  \   /
   v v
    A
```

I've tried specifying the port, but then the edges just wrap around. It doesn't change the position of the nodes.

Answer (score 11):

The solution is rankdir

```
digraph G {
 rankdir="BT"
 B->A
 C->A
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`rankdir` is the solution if you want to build your whole graph from bottom to top. A more flexible approach is to just tell the edges to point backward:

```
digraph G
{
    A -> B[ dir = back ];
    A -> C[ dir = back ];
}
```

yields

[image]

You could also write

```
A -> { B C }[ dir = back ];
```

Or you could give the general instructions for all edges defined after this instruction to point backward:

```
edge[ dir = back ];
```

This can be undone by

```
edge[ dir = forw ];
```

Hence,

```
digraph G
{
    edge[ dir = back ];
    A -> B;
    A -> C;
    edge[ dir = forw ];
    { B C } -> D;
}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: It's also possible to manipulate arrowtype to align the output to your assertion. But if you want it clean as possible without intrusion of direction rankdir should be the choice.